# Is it possible to optimize query using the EXISTS instead of IN clause with DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, exists

I have query which works.

```
select contract_no AS c_no, cm_mac AS c_mc, MIN(tstamp) as time2, sum(1) as aps
from devices where 
contract_no in 
(select distinct(contract_no) from devices where 
tstamp >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59' AND tstamp <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00')
group by contract_no, cm_mac;
```

I realized that query is slow so I was wondering if it is possible in anyway to optimize this query?
I was thinking maybe to use EXISTS instead of IN but in that case I cannot start with `EXISTS (SELECT 1 from .... where  contract_no= contract_no )` because I need this `DISTINCT` clause.

Of course I need to return same results.
Is this possible to somehow optimize this query?

```
UPDATE:
```

I checked feedbacks and you are right. If those two queries are executed I am getting the same results.
But the point is that the full query is more complex, and if I do not have this  sub query I am getting more results.

QUERY 1 (Returns 72 rows which is Correct):

```
    SELECT id, contract_no, customer, address, cm_mac, aps 
    FROM (select * from new_installed_devices where  insert4date >='2018-10-28' 
    AND insert4date <='2018-10-28' AND install_mark<2) as d1 
left join 
( select * from (select contract_no AS c_no, cm_mac AS c_mc, 
MIN(tstamp) as time2, sum(1) as aps from devices_change 
where contract_no in (select distinct(contract_no) from devices_change 
where tstamp >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59' AND tstamp <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00') 
group by contract_no, cm_mac ) as mtmbl 
where mtmbl.time2 >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59' and mtmbl.time2 <= '2018-10-29 
07:00:00' ) as tmp on d1.contract_no=tmp.c_no 
where aps>0 group by contract_no, customer, address, cm_mac;
```

QUERY 2 (Returns 75 rows which is not Correct) and this approach has your recommendation (to include two queries within the one):

```
SELECT id, contract_no, customer, address, cm_mac, aps  
FROM (select * from new_installed_devices where  insert4date >='2018-10-28' 
AND insert4date <='2018-10-28' AND install_mark<2) as d1 left join 
( select * from (select distinct(contract_no) AS c_no, cm_mac AS c_mc, 
MIN(tstamp) as time2, sum(1) as aps from devices_change 
where  tstamp >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59' AND tstamp <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00'
 group by contract_no, cm_mac ) as mtmbl 
where mtmbl.time2 >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59' and 
mtmbl.time2 <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00' ) as tmp 
on d1.contract_no=tmp.c_no 
where aps>0 group by contract_no, customer, address, cm_mac;
```

Comment: doesn't it work if you just have `where tstamp >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59' AND tstamp <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00')` with no subquery?

Comment: does not work!!!   additional repeated rows are returned which I do not want in result

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function on a column, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Simply write `select distinct contract_no ...` to make code clearer!

Comment: please provide a sample dataset here: http://sqlfiddle.com/ and share it so it's easier to help you. I think it's just a matter of adding "distinct" somewhere.

Comment: Why do you need select distinct in the sub-query? It doesn't give any result difference.

Comment: `contract_no in (select distinct` is the same as `contract_no in (select` (as checking if a value is in a list returns the same result if the list contains that value twice: it is still in that list). `group by` will also not give you duplicates. It is a little bit unclear which "additional repeated rows are returned which I do not want in result". Or is "I need a distinct" just under the assumption that it would speed up your query, and you are actually asking how to speed up your query? In that case, we need the execution plan (add `explain` infront of you query) and your indexes.

Comment: hi..sorry for late feedback... @jarih  I understand your point. But the thing is that these queries are actually one sub query on bigger query and if I go with approach to discard this subquery part I am getting more rows (3 additional rows) . Please take a look at my UPDATED queries and maybe you will be able to give me some hint. Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi..sorry for late feedback... @Solarflare  I understand your point. But the thing is that these queries are actually one sub query on bigger query and if I go with approach to discard this subquery part I am getting more rows (3 additional rows) . Please take a look at my UPDATED queries and maybe you will be able to give me some hint. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Solarflare can you please , if you know, what I should add in second query so I could limit the rows on the number returned from first query? I really cannot see the difference. My main point is to have optimized query, but of course with the same number of rows returned

Comment: The queries are different, and so they will return different rows! The 1st query looks for all contracts with a device_change in the date range and then excludes that contract if *any* (other) change of that device happened before the range, while the second query doesn't. It has nothing to do with distinct (and in fact, distinct has no effect in both queries). Choose the query that fits your requirements. If you want to optimized your query, add, as mentioned, explain plan and indexes (and probably some sample data and create table statements).

Comment: can you tell me how to execute explain plain? From that point you think I should be able to put some kind of optimization. Sorry I though that IN is the issue and that EXIST should provide some benefits

Comment: You can add `explain` directly infront of your query. Also make sure you decide which of those 2 you actually need. (contracts with changes in the range, or contracts with *first* change in that range). You should probably create a new question though, as it has nothing to do with your original one (which is asking about "distinct" in only part of the code, which, as it turned out, has not much to do with your actual problem). Make sure to add some sample data and the create table statements to make it easier to testyour (a bit messy and long) query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this version:

```
select contract_no AS c_no, cm_mac AS c_mc, min(tstamp) as time2, count(*) as aps
from devices d
where exists (select 1
              from devices d2
              where d2.contract_no = d.contract_no and
                    tstamp >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59' and
                    tstamp <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00'
              )
group by contract_no, cm_mac;
```

You want an index on `devices(contract-no, tstamp)`.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thanks for feedback but I am getting more results than my original code. Please take a look, I updated how the full query looks alike and maybe you will be able to give me some hint why multiple rows are returned if I try to exclude that one part of the subquery. Thank you in advance