# My SQL - trying to optimize Query returns more rows

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, query-optimization, distinct

I have one query which I inherit from my previous collegue, but I need to optimize it.

This query returns 72 rows.

```
SELECT  id, contract_no, customer, address, cm_mac, aps
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  *
            from  new_installed_devices
            where  insert4date >='2018-10-28'
              AND  insert4date <='2018-10-28'
              AND  install_mark<2
    ) as d1
    left join  
    (
        SELECT  *
            from  
            (
                SELECT  contract_no AS c_no, cm_mac AS c_mc, MIN(tstamp) as time2,
                        sum(1) as aps
                    from  devices_change
                    where  contract_no in (
                        SELECT  distinct(contract_no)
                            from  devices_change
                            where  tstamp >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59'
                              AND  tstamp <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00'
                          )
                    group by  contract_no, cm_mac 
            ) as mtmbl
            where  mtmbl.time2 >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59'
              and  mtmbl.time2 <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00' 
    ) as tmp  ON d1.contract_no=tmp.c_no
    where  aps>0
    group by  contract_no, customer, address, cm_mac;
```

It takes 20 seconds to execute.
I re-write it, trying to optimize it but in that case I have 75 rows (3 additional rows are returned), but result is presented in 2 seconds.

I have done like this (only difference is in one sub query):

```
SELECT  id, contract_no, customer, address, cm_mac, aps
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  *
            from  new_installed_devices
            where  insert4date >='2018-10-28'
              AND  insert4date <='2018-10-28'
              AND  install_mark<2
    ) as d1
    left join  
    (
        SELECT  *
            from  
            (
                SELECT distinct
                        (contract_no) AS c_no,
                        cm_mac AS c_mc, MIN(tstamp) as time2,
                        sum(1) as aps
                    from  devices_change
                    where  tstamp >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59'
                      AND  tstamp <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00'
                    group by  contract_no, cm_mac 
            ) as mtmbl
            where  mtmbl.time2 >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59'
              and  mtmbl.time2 <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00' 
    ) as tmp  ON d1.contract_no=tmp.c_no
    where  aps>0
    group by  contract_no, customer, address, cm_mac;
```

Like you see I did not change a lot in my case but still I am getting more rows that it should be in result.
Can someone please tell me the cause why my second query does not return completely correct result. I tried many things to optimize but without a success.
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Have you proved that your query is incorrect or are are you assuming it is because it's different?

Comment: Are the queries you posted exactly the same as what you are using? After reviewing them, I'm unsure why you would be getting extra rows. I did notice that you are using DISTINCT incorrectly, however. DISTINCT works on a per-row basis, not a per column basis. That said, I cannot immediately see why you are getting different results. I strongly recommended comparing the data and see if it is 3 new rows being returned, or more than 3 new ones, but also some old ones not being returned. Update your question with what you find.

Comment: @WillemRenzema I checked once more now.. I copy pasted and run these queires and yes definteky I am getting 3 more rows by the second query. In second query I am getting some contract no, which does noe exists in first query but also and getting duplicated contract no (duplicated value). I am defintely getting more rows I really tried now exeucitng those two queries. Also please check for similar topic - the second last answer from Solarflare. He thinks it is ok that I am receiving different results but I am not sure also how. Please assist me if you can

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101378/is-it-possible-to-optimize-query-using-the-exists-instead-of-in-clause-with-dist?noredirect=1#comment93102354_53101378

Comment: Even if you "did not change a lot", it's not the same query, and it's just faster because it has to do less work. Could you clarify what you are looking for? An explanation why they are different (I tried to explain that, but if that's what's bothering you, I can elaborate). Are you trying to optimize query 1? Then add the required details (explain, ...). What you currently seem to be asking is how to magically make query 2 return the correct results while keeping it as fast, which just doesn't work as easy as that.

Comment: Did you notice that those time ranges were 1 day + 2 seconds?!?

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `SELECT *` when you don't need all the columns.  It looks like `contract_no` is the only column needed from `dl`, hence from `new_installed_devices`.
- Is there some reason for testing `insert4date` for equality in that weird way?
- Recommend `INDEX(insert4date, install_mark, dl)` (in that order)
- Try to avoid the construct `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  Usually it is better to use `EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN`.
- Don't say `DISTINCT(contract_no), ...` -- `DISTINCT` is *not* a function; it's effect applies to the entire set of expressions.  Get rid of `DISTINCT` since the `GROUP BY` has that effect.
- Recommend `INDEX(contract_no, cm_max, tstamp)` (in that order)
- The test on mtmbl.time2 is redundant since `MIN(tstamp) is already limited to that (1 day + 2 second) time range.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

- You can replace the first subquery in the FROM clause with a direct reference to the table `new_installed_devices`, with some conditions in the WHERE clause. In older versions, MySQL doesn't handle subqueries very well, so try to avoid them in the FROM clause (especially if you have more than 1 or 2 of them).
- The range conditions for `mtmbl.time2` can be folded into the subquery's HAVING clause, to make sure you filter that data as quickly as possible, without creating a large temp table with that subquery.
- Can you provide the SHOW CREATE TABLE of these tables and the EXPLAIN for the query? It can be helpful.

When guessing the order MySQL will choose here, you can try to add these indexes and run the following query, to see if it works better. I applied the recommendations above to the query here below (hope my guesses about columns origins were correct, otherwise please fix everything accordingly):

```
ALTER TABLE `devices_change` ADD INDEX `devices_change_idx_no_mac_tstamp` (`contract_no`,`cm_mac`,`tstamp`);
ALTER TABLE `devices_change` ADD INDEX `devices_change_idx_tstamp_no` (`tstamp`,`contract_no`);
ALTER TABLE `new_installed_devices` ADD INDEX `new_installed_device_idx_no_insert4date` (`contract_no`,`insert4date`);
```

The query:

```
SELECT
        new_installed_devices.id,
        new_installed_devices.contract_no,
        new_installed_devices.customer,
        new_installed_devices.address,
        new_installed_devices.cm_mac,
        new_installed_devices.aps 
    FROM
        new_installed_devices AS d1 
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                * 
            FROM
                (SELECT
                    devices_change.contract_no AS c_no,
                    devices_change.cm_mac AS c_mc,
                    MIN(devices_change.tstamp) AS time2,
                    sum(1) AS aps 
                FROM
                    devices_change 
                WHERE
                    devices_change.contract_no IN (
                        SELECT
                            DISTINCT (devices_change.contract_no) 
                        FROM
                            devices_change 
                        WHERE
                            devices_change.tstamp >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59' 
                            AND devices_change.tstamp <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00'
                    ) 
                GROUP BY
                    devices_change.contract_no,
                    devices_change.cm_mac 
                HAVING
                    devices_change.time2 >= '2018-10-28 06:59:59' 
                    AND devices_change.time2 <= '2018-10-29 07:00:00' 
                ORDER BY
                    NULL) AS mtmbl) AS tmp 
                    ON d1.contract_no = tmp.c_no 
            WHERE
                aps > 0 
                AND d1.insert4date >= '2018-10-28' 
                AND d1.insert4date <= '2018-10-28' 
                AND d1.install_mark < 2 
            GROUP BY
                new_installed_devices.contract_no,
                new_installed_devices.customer,
                new_installed_devices.address,
                new_installed_devices.cm_mac 
            ORDER BY
                NULL
```